# Why keyup event fire in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox, dom-events

I bind some events to textarea. `keydown` and `keyup` works well in Chrome, but not in Firefox:

You can copy the following code in the console of firebug to try out.

Firefox version: 7.0.1

OS: Ubuntu

```
function mykeydown(e) {
  console.log('keydown');
} 

function mykeyup(e) {
  console.log('keyup');
}

function bindEvent(el, eventName, eventHandler) {
  if (el.addEventListener){
    el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false); 
  } else if (el.attachEvent){
    el.attachEvent('on'+eventName, eventHandler);
  }
}

var text = document.createElement('textarea');
bindEvent(text, 'keydown', mykeydown);   
bindEvent(text, 'keyup', mykeyup);
document.body.appendChild(text);
```

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/eHBWw/

Comment: @xdazz do the events fire when you typing abcd...?

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing keydown and keyup in the console.